# Pre element not respecting right padding

Tags: html, css, pre

I have a pre element with the following styles:

```
pre {
    background: #555;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#555 50%, #505050 50%);
    background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(#555 50%, #505050 50%);
    background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(#555 50%, #505050 50%);
    background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(#555 50%, #505050 50%);
    background-image:         linear-gradient(#555 50%, #505050 50%);
    background-position: 0 0;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-size: 4.5em 4.5em;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: .8em;
    line-height: 2.25;
    margin: 0 -2.25em 2.25em;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 2.25em;
}
```

Why, when scrolling the `pre` element, is the right padding being ignored? I don't want long lines to wrap, I want this behavior (it is not expected behaviour based on the specification, but seems to work in webkit): http://jsfiddle.net/joshnh/Ly5kz/

Here is a link to a live example: http://joshnh.com/2012/08/14/making-a-pure-css-featured-image-slider/#step1

Comment: Giving the parent element to the `<pre>` an explicit width works in Chrome but not in IE or Firefox. (see [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qf6As/2/).) You may want to consider using `<code>` or another tag instead.

Comment: While that might work, it isn't actually dealing with the core issue; it is just a work-around. If you check out the jsFiddle that I have linked to in the question, you will see that browsers naturally do what I want, so I'm trying to figure out what is stopping it from working in my case.

Comment: Your JSFiddle does not work as you expect in FireFox 15 or IE9. It works in Chrome because you've given `<body>` an explicit width.

Comment: True, I was able to replicate that issue. Any ideas? Poor browser implementation? Bug in Chrome?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not quite how padding works. If your content is being forced past the edge of the box it will continue on without being covered by the background. Padding is room around the inner section of the box. All text that *fits* in the box will have x amount of space between it and the box edge.

In order to have a padding-like matte/box/border you'll need to have a wrapper div that has the border and padding and add your other styles to the pre.

http://jsfiddle.net/ktJ3g/

Comment: A different implementation I guess. If padding covered text that was too wide many pages would be unreadable.

Comment: I had a bit more of a poke around the specification, and I think you have hit the nail on the head. If you look at the live example I linked to in the question, how would you solve the issue I'm having?

Comment: Did you check the fiddle in my answer? Putting a wrapper with your border and padding styles will give you that matte look (I believe that's what your're going for, correct?). I can't think of a way to do it without a wrapper element.

Comment: I did have a look, but that doesn't match what is on my site. If you check it out you will see that the scroll bar sits below the pre element; that is the desired behavior. I'm not opposed to the use of a wrapper element, but it cannot behave as your example does.

Comment: Don't have a ton of time, but I got it looking passable: http://jsfiddle.net/kLwn6/ - When I added this code to your page in inspector (the new div and pre styles) the scrollbar was positioned mostly correct as well. You'll need to do some extra tweaking though.

Comment: Thanks for your time, it's not exactly what I'm after, I guess I'll just put up with the lack of padding on the right.

Answer (score 0):

pre elements are white-space:nowrap by default, you need to set some sort of wrap attribute. Here are your options: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp

Comment: Firstly, pre elements are white-space: pre; by default, and secondly, changing that doesn't fix the issue. Perhaps it isn't clear enough in the question, but I do not want wrapping (hence the use of the scrollbar).

Comment: Thank you for editing your question, and downvoting me because I am not psychic. You're right about the white-space:pre, though, my mistake.

Comment: Actually, if you refer to the original question, you will find that I simply asked for right padding on what I already had. It was you that assumed that wrapping was an acceptable answer. Please don't take out your frustration on me for making an incorrect assumption, being psychic has nothing to do with it. I have clarified my question to eliminate further assumptions. But either way, your answer was wrong.

Comment: Only in Chrome, still no luck in Firefox or IE.

Comment: Looks like it's a known bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=372498 - this one mentions the pre specifically: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=446601 - note that your fiddle doesn't work in Firefox either.

Answer (score 0):

Try white-space: pre-wrap; - Also, I think your kind of abusing the lang attribute by using it to identify the content as containing html or css. I believe it should be used to indicate the language encoding of the content, i.e. en_US, fr_FR, etc

Comment: As stated in my question, wrapping long lines is not an option.

Comment: Sorry - didn't notice that the first time. So, what is it you want to do with the lines that are too long? You can either remove the max-width property on the container, or maybe use overflow:hide to truncate the excess

Comment: Refer to the jsFiddle I have now added to the question. That should pretty clearly show expected (and desired) behavior. In regards to not noticing, that's fine, but why are you (and others) assuming that wrapping is an acceptable answer when I am only asking why the padding isn't working on a pre element that scrolls (i.e. doesn't wrap)? I don't mean to be rude, I just can't figure it out. Obviously I know exactly what I want, but I would have thought that asking why padding isn't working on a scrolling element fairly clearly demonstrates that scrolling is the desired behavior, not wrapping?

Comment: Also, thanks for the heads up regarding the language encoding. I will fix that when I get time (it is used on many posts).

Comment: Also, when I tried the demo in FF, the four little dots seem to track the mouse and even disappear from view under certain conditions. You can certainly add an overflow:scroll property to the <pre>.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by four little dots? Anyway, it turns out that the of the lang attribute is what causes it! I will replace lang with data-lang. Although it still doesn't seem to be working in Firefox or IE.

Answer (score 0):

A note for prism.js-based `<pre>` elements:

You can use the `normalize-whitespace` plugin:

```
import 'prismjs/plugins/normalize-whitespace/prism-normalize-whitespace';
```

- https://prismjs.com/plugins/normalize-whitespace/
- https://github.com/PrismJS/prism/tree/master/plugins