# Inner div with preformatted whitespace does not respect the right padding of the parent

Tags: css

My goal is to have some preformatted text to fit into a div with horizontal scroll while being padded on all sides. However, the inner div in my code does not respect the right padding of the parent, and I am not sure why.

*This question **seems** to be closely related to [Pre element not respecting right padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12255597/pre-element-not-respecting-right-padding), however, both the question and the answer are from 2012, there is no code in the answers there and the links to jsfiddle are dead, so it is practically useless*

```css
.outer {
  width: 10rem;
  overflow-x: auto;
  background: grey;
  padding: 3rem;
  border-radius: 1rem;
}

.inner {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore
magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Apparently, the solution is to add `display: grid` to the `outer` class. It works in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari. Example: https://codepen.io/sonic435342/pen/PoaodKz

Answer (score 0):

You can make the width of the child `fit-content`:

```css
.outer {
  width: 10rem;
  overflow-x: auto;
  background: grey;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  padding: 3rem;
}

.inner {
  white-space: pre;

  width: intrinsic; /* Safari (?) */
  width: -moz-fit-content; /* Firefox */
  width: fit-content; 
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore
magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this solution works only in Chrome, but not in Safari or Firefox, which is very strange as `width: fit-content` has been supposedly supported for years by all three https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_width_fit-content - I still need a more cross-browser solution

Comment: Unfortunately, the changes you made still do not work in Firefox and Safari. In any case, thank you for spending your time to help me!